# how to provide Windows env variable values in vm arguments?

Tags: java, dos

i want to set a jvm variable with any of the Windows environment variables, say suppose WINDIR. ie is there way i can set as -Dwindir=WINDIR where the windir will have the value of WINDIR.

EDIT: when tried with -Dwindir=WINDIR it is directly assigning a string value of "WINDIR" which i am not interested in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First if you want to pass environment variable to JVM on windows use % sign: -Dwinddir=%WINDIR%.
This is not java. This is DOS.

Second, you do not need it in most cases. Use `System.getenv()` instead. Probably it contains all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Enclosing the environment variable in percent signs should do it:

```
-Dwindir=%WINDIR%
```

Comment: Care to tell HOW it didn't work? Or should we ask our crystal ball?

Comment: i had given in vm arguments like -Dwindir=%WINDIR% and using the variable windir in the logj.properties to name the file. its creating a file with the name %WINDIR%.

Comment: In that case I suspect you will find that WINDIR is not defined as an environment variable.